# Is there a command line flag for "Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate" in certbot-nginx?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a script which daily runs the command
`certbot --nginx -d $DOMAIN`

for a number of domains to renew their certificate

```
You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/****.conf)

What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate
2: Renew & replace the certificate (may be subject to CA rate limits)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): Cert not yet due for renewal
```

I always pick 1 if the certificate is not close to expiry. Is there a flag I can pass to the command to make it always pick 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running the command with the [`-n` parameter](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#certbot-command-line-options):

> Run without ever asking for user input. This may
> require additional command line flags; the client will
> try to explain which ones are required if it finds one
> missing

If that doesn't help you can use the common methods to answer questions of command line tools:

1. Piping the answer into the command

   ```
   echo "1" | certbot [...]
   ```
2. use [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)
3. Use other means to edit the config file, e.g. `sed` or a configuration management solution of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using

`certbot renew`

which does everything automatically

> renew acts on multiple certificates and always takes into account
> whether each one is near expiry. Because of this, renew is suitable
> (and designed) for automated use, to allow your system to
> automatically renew each certificate when appropriate. Since renew
> only renews certificates that are near expiry it can be run as
> frequently as you want - since it will usually take no action.

https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#renewing-certificates

If your `certbot` installation was done properly, there is most probably a cron job already setup that does this (so you do not have to do this yourself manually). I recently installed `certbot` in a ubuntu 22 server using [snap](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#snap) and a cronjob in `/etc/cron.d/certbot` was automatically added.